# Automapper - create custom property map where source object isn't known and property names don't match?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

That title is confusing. It's a little easier to show with code. Here are the background classes:

```
public interface ISearch { }

public class Search1 : ISearch
{
    public string PROP1 { get; set; }
}

public class Search2 : ISearch
{
    public string PROP2 { get; set; }
}

public class SearchFinal
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to do:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    IMapper mapper;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        //This config fails validation
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<ISearch, SearchFinal>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop1, opts => opts.MapFrom("PROP1"))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop2, opts => opts.MapFrom("PROP2"));
        });
        mapper = new Mapper(config);
    }

    public void SearchMethod(ISearch search)
    {
        SearchFinal test = mapper.Map<SearchFinal>(search);

        // Do query stuff
    }
}
```

The config fails validation at run-time because the "PROP1" / "PROP2" properties don't exist in the interface. Is there a way to set this map up? Any other ways around this problem without restructuring this admit-ably ugly code structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create maps for each interface implementations (thus you also will use mappings only for properties which exist in each class - i.e. no attempt to map `Prop2` for `Search1` class):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Search1, SearchFinal>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PROP1));

    cfg.CreateMap<Search2, SearchFinal>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop2, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PROP2));
});
```

Next pass some implementation of `ISearch` interface which is mapped to `SearchFinal`:

```
ISearch search = new Search1 { PROP1 = "foo" };
// note that you are mapping variable of ISearch type here
SearchFinal test = mapper.Map<SearchFinal>(search);
```

Output:

```
{
  "Prop1": "foo",
  "Prop2": null
}
```

Comment: Awsome, thank you! I love simple answers. I'm not sure why I didn't think I could pass ISearch into the map method if it wasn't defined in the config!